# [Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.]

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

During testing I have this error:  `console.error Error: Uncaught [Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.]`

I was looking for solutions and everyone said to use BrowserRouter - I use it, but the error still occurs. Can anyone give a hint what I'm doing wrong?

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App/>
        </BrowserRouter>,
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js:

```
    import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import CharacterList from './components/CharacterList/CharacterList';
import CharacterDetail from './components/CharacterDetail/CharacterDetail';

function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<CharacterList/>}/>
            <Route path="/character/:id" element={<CharacterDetail/>}/>
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I use useNavigate in both CharacterList and CharacyerDetail

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add routes at index.js, you may update it as below:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

and update your app.js as

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<CharacterList/>}/>
        <Route path="/character/:id" element={<CharacterDetail/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
 )}
export default App;
```